# WPS Office hijacking Webview of my App

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a very basic Android Application, which uses webview to show content. I have multiple html pages in the asset folder and on app launch, I load index.html pages in webview and then the app keep showing information in webview.

The app works perfect unless someone has WPS office installed on the same device. With WPS office, the app able to load index.html on app launch but as soon as you click on any link on this, it launched WPS office and shows error "Files no longer exists. The file may be renamed, moved, cleared or deleted by other programs".

Please suggest how to avoid launching WPS offie and what is causing this error as this is simple webview only with pages linked in HTML.

Comment: Open the WPS office app settings, Clear defaults

Comment: @cricket_007: nope this does not work. Also, the problem here is, how to do this programatically, as I can't go to all of people who have downloaded my app and clear defaults settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just override url loading to solve this problem.

This example works:

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(webview);
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```